# Devolver valores de una tabla concreta en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Acabo de resolver cómo obtener el nombre de un selector como variable y mandarlo a través del cliente en js a nodejs.

Dicho problema empieza aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De este `SELECTOR` obtengo uno de los nombres que hay puestos como `OPTION`.

A través de esta función lo mando al servidor con `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
const select = document.getElementById('members');

select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    sendVariable(e.target.value);
});

function sendVariable(name) {
    let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xml.open("POST", "/");
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xml.send(JSON.stringify({name}));
}
```

Así lo recojo en el server con nodejs:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name;
});
```

Y ahora me gustaría poder mandar una SQL concreta:

`SELECT * FROM name`

Tengo un ejemplo que ya he probado y no me deja hacerlo así:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // about mysql
    connection.getConnection(function(error, tempCont) {
        if(!!error) {
            tempCont.release();
            console.log('Error');
        } else {
            tempCont.query("SELECT * FROM Oscar", function(error,rows,fields) {
                tempCont.release();
                if(!!error) {
                    console.log('Error in the query');
                } else {
                    console.log(rows);
                    res.json(rows);
                }
                res.end();
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Por tanto, mi intención es poder hacer que, en cuanto reciba el nombre en el servidor, lance dicha sql y pueda ver la sentencia en el cliente de alguna forma.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

---

**[EDIT]**

---

Ahora he conseguido sacar la tabla en el servidor con el ejemplo de arriba. Pero necesito pasarlo de alguna forma al cliente para poder trabajar con esa información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(No pretendo mostrar código, solamente la consola terminal)

¿Cómo podía mandarlo al cliente de nuevo?

Answer (score 0):

Vale nada, ya lo tengo. Seguramente sea algo chapuza lo que hice aquí, pero de momento me gusta, estoy abierto a mejoras.

Esto por parte del server en nodejs

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name;

    connection.getConnection(function(error, tempCont) {
        if(!!error) {
            tempCont.release();
            console.log('Error');
        } else {
            tempCont.query("SELECT * FROM " + name, function(error,rows,fields) {
                tempCont.release();
                if(!!error) {
                    console.log('Error in the query');
                } else {
                    //console.log(rows); // esto mandarlo al cliente para poder trabajar con ello de alguna forma
                    sendValues(rows);
                }
            });

        }
    });
});

function sendValues(rows) {
    console.log(rows);

    app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
        res.send(rows);
    });

}
```

y esto por parte del cliente:

```
function sendVariable(name) {
    let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xml.open("POST", "/");
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xml.send(JSON.stringify({name}));

    setTimeout( function(){
        readData();
    }, 100)
}

function readData(){
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/data')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => viewData(data));
}

function viewData(data){

    //aqui trabajare con los datos

}
```